# Flume twitter config error

Tags: flume, hadoop2, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am trying to extract twitter data using flume. but i am getting the following error

```
15/04/08 23:16:36 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Unhandled error
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.conf.Configuration.isStallWarningsEnabled()Z
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:60)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40)
at com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.<init>(TwitterSource.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:42)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:327)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have used the  flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar from cloudera.The TwitterAgent runs with the above mentioned error.
Is there any work around for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add more content to your question. What did you do to provoke this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a dependency error. the flume-sources library expects a version of Twitter4j that isn't present, hence the NoSuchMethod error. I would suggest that you pull the right versions, whihc would be

1.6.0-SNAPSHOT for twitter source and 3.0.3 for twitter4j. You should consult flume's pom.xml, which has all the version info you need.

It should be noted that you should use the most current version as possible, as old implementations will not work. Twitter broke their old APIs in the meantime.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where can we download 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT jar?

Comment: You'll need to check out the flume sources for that and build with maven.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with fully qualified name of the Class in your Agent.conf file.
In the older versions, class name is:  com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
In the latest version of the flume TwitterSource is already shipped and no need to download separately. 
The class name is changed to org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource

Please carefully change the class name, defitely It will work for you